# Restricting function template types in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Is there any way in Visual Studio 2012 to restrict function templates to specific types?

This one works in GCC, but MSVC generates `error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class float_t, class = typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point<float_t>::value >::type>
inline float_t floor(float_t x)
{
    float_t result;
    //...
    return result;
}
```

A cross compiler solution would be the best. Any alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you would write this as

```
template <class float_t>
typename std::enable_if< std::is_floating_point<float_t>::value, float_t>::type
  floor(float_x x) {...}
```

That's how `enable_if` is intended to be used.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's how enable_if is intended to be used or how it's normally used. This is just to bypass VS2012's lack of support for default template parameters in functions.

Comment: @Rapptz: That was the original way that enable_if was intended to be used. The default function template parameter is a new thing, relative to enable_if.

Comment: @DeadMG I won't disagree. However since C++11 it's usually placed in the template parameters. Anyway, this is a perfect workaround if your compiler lacks support for it.

Comment: Yes, that's fair enough. But claiming that enable_if is not intended to be used like this is simply incorrect.

Comment: That means that in a compiler that supports default template parameters, my original solution fits better in the way of C++11 standard?